# C Send Socket without Defining Socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

What does this line of code do

```
send(4, "test\n", 15, 0);
```

If there is no socket defined in the code?

Comment: That line attempts to send(2) the six bytes `'t'`, `'e'`, `'s'`, `'t'`, `'\n'`, `'\0'` *and then the next nine contiguous bytes*, whatever those may be, to file descriptor 4, whatever that may be.  What, specifically, are you asking?

Comment: So file descriptor 4 is /dev/fd/4 ? When i set it with: exec 4<> testfd it doesn't write it.

Answer (score 6):

It probably fails, with a `EBADF` error (in `errno`).

See the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send) for more possible error values.

Note that it *could* succeed, if there is code before it that sets up a socket with a hardcoded descriptor value of `4` (the first argument). See the [`dup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) function for one way of attempting to do that.

Also note that it could be a *parent process* doing that setup, so it might not even be visible in the source file but just silently assumed.

Finally note the undefined behavior due to reading outside the provided buffer (the string isn't 15 characters long). This is pretty suspect code.

Comment: Is there a way to create the socket in a separate file and have it work?

Comment: @h00j, I guess a more flexible way to do that would be to send the socket descriptor using some [inter-process communication mechanism](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ipc.html). This is because the descriptor allotted to your socket could change every time. Your code is broken if it hard codes this.

Comment: It could also fail with a SIGSEGV depending on whether the 9 bytes of memory beyond the literal are mapped or not. Even if it succeeds completely it will send 9 bytes of junk.